# как удалить nginx в ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Попробовал все обычные способы которые нашел в Интернет, но все равно когда ввожу localhost выпадает страница что nginx работает. Как его полностью удалить?

Comment: Перед удалением процесс nginx останавливали? sudo service nginx stop?

Comment: Проверьте не висит ли процесс в памяти при помощи ps aux | grep nginx.

Comment: да, останавливал

Comment: пишет что удален, но все равно в локалхосте показывает что работает

Comment: ss -tunap | grep '80\|443' что говорит? Там точно nginx вообще?

Comment: Может быть у вас страница закэшировалась в браузере?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Помогло

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx*

sudo apt-get purge nginx*
```

Answer (score 3):

Проверьте что у Вас весит на 80 порту. Это можно сделать командой:

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 80
```

В результате вы увидите что запущенно у Вас на localhost. Если это процесс nginx то выполните команду:

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

Answer (score 2):

Если **nginx** удалён, то скорее всего у вас остались в системе пакеты, которые устанавливались вместе с **nginx** автоматически.
Выполните следующую серию команд:

Получим ответ, что **nginx** удалён:
`sudo apt remove nginx`

Получим ответ, что **nginx** удалён с указанием оставшихся пакетов:
`sudo apt purge nginx`

Удаление пакетов установленных автоматически с **nginx**, но более неиспользуемые:
`sudo apt autoremove`

Answer (score 0):

можно вот так:

```
kill -9 $(netstat -ntlp | grep nginx | head -n 1 | awk {'print $7'} | cut -d '/' -f 1)
```

Но это будет немного грубовато, но зато соответствует "совсем удалить"